# What is gnuplot's internal representation of floating point numbers?

Tags: gnuplot, floating-point-precision

I'm sure the answer is obvious but I can't find it without looking at the source.

What is gnuplot's internal representation of floating point numbers? Is it the platform's `double`? Does it use its own internal representation? Can it do arbitrary precision?

Comment: Funny, I used `gnuplot precision` in an appropriative service and didn't need to look at any source .. ("sometimes" to float, "usually" to double, "no" to arbitrary)

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the search term. If you post this as an answer, I'm happy yo accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search will turn up that calculations are done in double precision whenever possible, however, there's a little sublety going on here.  The range of an IEEE double precision number should go up to more than `1.797e308`, however, if you try to give gnuplot a number that big, it chokes:

```
gnuplot> plot '-' u 0:($1/2.)
input data ('e' ends) > 1.7976931348623157e+308
input data ('e' ends) > 30
input data ('e' ends) > e
Warning: empty x range [1:1], adjusting to [0.99:1.01]
Warning: empty y range [15:15], adjusting to [14.85:15.15]
```

Now if you show gnuplot's range variables:

```
gnuplot> show variables all
```

You'll see some things that are a little strange:

```
GPVAL_DATA_X2_MIN = 8.98846567431158e+307
GPVAL_DATA_X2_MAX = -8.98846567431158e+307
```

With this number repeated a few times.  (Note that this number is *roughly* correct):

```
gnuplot> !python -c 'import sys; print sys.float_info.max/2.'
8.98846567431e+307
```

**(python's float is the system's double precision).

Now a little playing around:

```
gnuplot> a = 8.98846567431e+307
gnuplot> a = 8.98846567432e+307
             ^
         undefined value
```

So presumably gnuplot's floating point numbers go up to the system's maximum for double precision (where possible) divided by 2.